# cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py builds the same graph again and again?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

I am looking at the multi-GPU implementation in cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

the tower_loss() function called the following code to build up a convolution graph (line 78)

```
logits = cifar10.inference(images)
```

Internally, inference() takes images input and builds a neural network graph and creates output logits. My question is, apparently, tower_loss() will be called thousands of times in a real training, therefore the graph building of exactly the same structure and operations but different images would be repeating again and again. Would this be efficient? Why not it creates the graph only once by constructing the graph only once, say, build_tower(), and later on feed different images via feed_dict

This occurs to me another question, is ops graph in tensorflow.run(ops, feed_dict) a cached object or not, I do not know the underlining implementation here, but if the graph is not a cached object, then this would be equivalent to rebuilding the ops graph every time when being called; If it is a cached, the multi gpu cifar10 code seems very inefficient because it rebuilds the same thing repeatedly.

Comment: My understanding is, the graph will be built once; `tower_loss()`, as well as any other functions written in Python or C++, will be called once; `sess.run()` will be called multiple times using a `for/while` loop but each time it executes the same pre-defined graph. At runtime, the Python/C++ code (that involves TensorFlow tensors and ops) will be converted/pruned to C code and executed. For more info, see [TensorFlow architecture](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture).

Comment: @Richard_wth, thank you for your comment. I think your understanding makes sense. I think sometimes I am a little confused about tensorflow infrastructure. I just wonder, for example, if in the graph, we have defined a placeholder with a shape of unknown size in some dimension like shape=(None, 10), I do not know how tensorflow can handle the pre-allocation of the input, do the optimization and cached this pre-defined graph for the future usage which would be called upon thousands of times by .run()

Comment: I think the memory is not pre-allocated until you call `sess.run()` where input needs to be provided to the placeholder. Eventually the input is acquired from variables in memory or files with fixed batch_size (thus not `None`) for each iteration. The memory is allocated after the C code is obtained (thus inside `sess.run()`). As a result, the TensorfFlow out of memory error only happens at `sess.run()`. You may come across OOM with an unreasonably large batch_size.